# Prove $f(f^{-1}(x))=x$

Tags: inverse-function, function-and-relation-composition

If we have a problem $f(x)=x$ it's mean $x=f^{-1}(x)$. Hence if $f(x)=x$, then $f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$

But behind the problem, we know that we must take the inverse for both sides. And it leaves $f^{-1}(f(x))=f(f^{-1}(x))=x$

How do i prove $f(f^{-1}(x))=x$ ?
I can't found it on any books. 
Sorry for the stupid question....

I know that all of us already know about this. But if someone asks me "how do you prove this?" I don't know how to answer this.

Comment: What does $f^{-1}$ really _mean_ to you? Think about that, and the answer to your question might come to you.

Comment: @Arthur Inverse? f to the negative one? Sorry i don't get it.

Comment: @user516076 what is your *definition* of inverse function?

Comment: @drhab As for as i know is if A represents as Domain and B as Codomain. Inverse function is B×A? idk...

Comment: I don't really care about what you _call_ it. I care what you think it _means_. What is, to you, the fundamental relationship between $f$ and $f^{-1}$? What is it that sets $f^{-1}$ apart from any other function?

Comment: Don't ask me. I can't tell you what mathematical meaning _you_ put into the symbol $f^{-1}$. This is something you must know yourself. And until you're certain of what you yourself think, this problem is out of your reach. You say you have books. What do they say?

Comment: That's why i'm asking on this forum right.. idk. ok sorry. I'll study more..

Comment: Not at all. You're allowed to ask questions, and I think our giudelines specifically state "at any level". I'm just trying to help you help yourself. I might have been too harsh. It's difficult to judge some times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

''If we have a problem f(x)=x it's mean x=f−1(x). Hence if f(x)=x, then f(x)=f−1(x).''

Well, if $f(x)=x$ for all $x$, then $f$ is the identity map whose inverse is the identity map as well.

''But behind the problem, we know that we must take the inverse for both sides. And it leaves f−1(f(x))=f(f−1(x))=x.''

Well, a function $f:A\rightarrow A$ is invertible if there is a function $g:A\rightarrow A$ such that $fg = id =gf$ where $id$ is the identity mapping.

One can show that the invertible is uniquely determined so that we can write $f^{-1}$ for the inverse of $f$. Then we have $f^{-1}f = id = ff^{-1}$.
Moreover, a function is invertible iff it is both injective and surjective.

Answer (score 2):

Say $f$ is injective. If $\color{red}{y=f(x)}$ then $f^{-1}(\color{red}{y})=x$ so $f^{-1}(\color{red}{f(x)})=x$

Answer (score 1):

Function $f:A\to B$ has an inverse function if and only there are functions $g,h:B\to A$ such that $f\circ g$ and $h\circ f$ are identities.

If such functions exists then it can be shown that the functions $g,h$ are unique and coincide.

This opens the possibility to speak of the inverse of $f$ and to denote it without ambiguity as $f^{-1}$.

So the characteristic properties of $f^{-1}$ are $f\circ f^{-1}=\mathsf{id}_B$ and $f^{-1}\circ f=\mathsf{id}_A$, which means that *by definition* we have $f(f^{-1}(x))=x$ for every $x\in B$ and $f^{-1}(f(x))=x$ for every $x\in A$.

Also it well known that $f$ has an inverse function if and only if $f$ is bijective.

Comment: I'm lookimg for this... thanks